# change starting buffer from *scratch* to recentf-open-files

Tags: buffers, start-up, recentf, scratch-buffer

I like the buffer that is opened when type M-x recentf-open-files. I'd love to have it as my starting buffer instead of *scratch*, but I don't know how.

I've tried adding '(initial-buffer-choice 'recentf-open-files) and '(initial-buffer-choice '(recentf-open-files)) and some other variations of this function call (I don't know elisp) to my init.el following what I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083181/how-to-load-file-into-buffer-and-switch-to-buffer-on-start-up-in-emacs) but nothing seems to work.

I'm pretty sure this is an easy one, but couldn't put it together yet.

PS: I'm on mac os running emacs 28.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```el
(recentf-mode)
(setq initial-buffer-choice #'recentf-open-files)
```

at the end of your init file. If you have a customization file, you probably want to delete any `initial-buffer-choice` entry or there will a fight.

Untested (I find `recentf` more a PITA than a help).

EDIT: I removed the `(require 'recentf)` line, since `recentf-mode` is autoloaded.